# How to have String.Format properly pad it's time with zeroes and colons

Tags: vb.net, string, timespan, stopwatch

I have the following piece of code in my VB program. What I noticed is that the timer label will show the time 59:59 then 0:00.

What I would like to have happen is the timer to display 1:00:00 but can't seem to get this correct.

```
Private Sub tmrShowTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrShowTimer.Tick
    ' Timer Event to handle the StopWatch counting the "Show Timer" hopefully this doesn't get too full.
    Dim tsShowElapsed As TimeSpan = Me.stwShowTimer.Elapsed

    If tsShowElapsed.Hours >= 1 Then
        lblShowTimer.Font = New Font(lblShowTimer.Font.Name, 18)
    End If


    lblShowTimer.Text = String.Format("{1:#0}:{2:00}",
                             Math.Floor(tsShowElapsed.TotalHours),
                              tsShowElapsed.Minutes,
                              tsShowElapsed.Seconds)
End Sub
```

What am I missing to get this to correctly format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a little more compact, like so:

```
lblShowTimer.Text = tsShowElapsed.ToString(If(tsShowElapsed.Hours > 0, "h\:mm\:ss", "m\:ss").ToString)
```

But yeah, I think you'll always have to use a conditional to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a check for hours you could do this

```
Private Sub tmrShowTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrShowTimer.Tick
    ' Timer Event to handle the StopWatch counting the "Show Timer" hopefully this doesn't get too full.
    'Me.stwShowTimer.Elapsed is a timespan
    If Me.stwShowTimer.Elapsed.Hours >= 1 Then
        lblShowTimer.Font = New Font(lblShowTimer.Font.Name, 18)
        lblShowTimer.Text = Me.stwShowTimer.Elapsed.ToString("h\:mm\:ss")
    Else
        lblShowTimer.Text = Me.stwShowTimer.Elapsed.ToString("m\:ss")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh right, I could combine these into one conditional

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to edit the program to involve a conditional, there might be abetter way to do this but here is what I have:

```
    If tsShowElapsed.Hours > 0 Then
        strFormat = "{0:#0}:{1:#0}:{2:00}"
    Else
        strFormat = "{1:#0}:{2:00}"
    End If


    lblShowTimer.Text = String.Format(strFormat,
                             Math.Floor(tsShowElapsed.TotalHours),
                              tsShowElapsed.Minutes,
                              tsShowElapsed.Seconds)
```